# Why is "deleteBlocks" not working in phpWord?

Tags: block, phpword

I´m trying to use blocks in my Word document but I´m having some problems. First of all, when I declare a block in my document, if I don´t use the function "cloneBlock", the result appears like this:

```
${sec}
example
${/sec}
```

Maybe I must use that function to appear properly. But my main problem is that "deleteBlock" is not working. If I don´t clone the block, the generated docx is corrupted. But if I clone the block, the function "deleteBlock" doesn´t delete the block and it appear the information that is inside that block in my final docx file.

This is my code:

```
//Word
// Creating the new document...
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('../example.docx');
//set value
//$templateProcessor->setValue('title', 'Example');

//Triplicate block
$templateProcessor->cloneBlock('firstblock', 3, true, true);
$templateProcessor->setValue('firstname#1', 'John');
$templateProcessor->setValue('lastname#1', 'Doe');
$templateProcessor->setValue('firstname#2', 'John');
$templateProcessor->setValue('lastname#2', 'Doe');
$templateProcessor->setValue('firstname#3', 'John');
$templateProcessor->setValue('lastname#3', 'Doe');

//Delete Block
$templateProcessor->cloneBlock('sec', 1, true, true);
$templateProcessor->deleteBlock('sec');
$templateProcessor->saveAs('example.docx');
```

Docx template:

```
${firstblock}
Hello ${firstname} ${lastname}!
${/firstblock}
${sec}
example
${/sec}
```

UPDATE:
Instead of using the function "deleteBlock", I have use the function "cloneBlock" like this and it deletes the block:

```
//Delete Block
$templateProcessor->cloneBlock('sec', 0, true, true);
```

So, I have write to clone the block 0 times, so it disappears
But I have another problem. I don´t know why, but this only works sometimes

Comment: have you found the solution? currently i end up create multiple template files since I cannot delete block or row

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why user @d1845412 deleted their previous answer, but it actually solved my issue. I overwrote the deleteBlock method with the following code and it seems to work. I prefer this small change over larger changes to the replaceBlock method.

```php7
/**
 * Override this method since deleteBlock doesn't seem to work.
 * @param string $blockname
 */
public function deleteBlock($blockname)
{
    $this->cloneBlock($blockname, 0, true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I slightly changed the regexp in replaceBlock, I also added a function that removes unused patterns, it may come in handy) I'll warn you right away - not really testing so use it carefully

```php
class PatchedTemplateProcessor extends TemplateProcessor
{
    /**
     *  Remove ${*} and ${/*} from temporary document
     */
    public function removeSearchPatterns()
    {
        preg_match_all(
            '/(\$\{[^\}]*\})/',
            $this->tempDocumentMainPart,
            $matches,
            PREG_SET_ORDER
        );


        foreach ($matches as $match){
            $this->tempDocumentMainPart = str_replace(
                $match,
                '',
                $this->tempDocumentMainPart
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $blockname
     * @param string $replacement
     */
    public function replaceBlock($blockname, $replacement)
    {
        $matches = array();
        preg_match(
            '/(<w:t.*>\${' . $blockname . '}<\/w:.*?t>)(.*)(<w:t.*\${\/' . $blockname . '}<\/w:.*?t>)/is',
            $this->tempDocumentMainPart,
            $matches
        );

        if (isset($matches[3])) {
            $this->tempDocumentMainPart = str_replace(
                $matches[2] . $matches[3],
                $replacement,
                $this->tempDocumentMainPart
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete a block of text.
     *
     * @param string $blockname
     */
    public function deleteBlock($blockname)
    {
        $this->replaceBlock($blockname, '');
    }
}
```